# How to use wildcard in PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table filter feature in PHP club membership webpage. I made it so the user can filter the table and choose which members to display in a table. For example, he can choose the country or state where the member is from then hit display. I am using a prepared statement.

The problem is, I need to use wildcards to make the coding easier. How do I use a wildcard in PHP MySQL query? I will use wildcards for example if the user does NOT want specific country but instead he wants to display all members from all countries.

I know not specifying the `WHERE country=` will automatically select any countries but I already constructed it so each controls like the SELECT control for country already has a value like "CA" or "NY" and "*" if the user leaves that control under "All Countries". This value when submitted is then added to the query like:

```
$SelectedCountry = $_POST["country"];
sql .= " WHERE country=" . $SelectedCountry;
```

But the problem is using `WHERE country=*` doesn't seem to work. No errors, just doesn't work. Is "*" the wildcard in PHP MySQL?

Comment: You could use like and then put the `%` sign in. That doesn't look like you are using prepared statements correctly though..

Comment: Yes I tried that, doesn't seem to work. I assigned it to a variable first `$Bind_country = "'%'";` then included it in my mysqli_stmt_bind_param. It is not working right, it is not displaying any results. It works if I select a specific country but not when using * or %. The query on that area would have been `WHERE country='%'`

Comment: Don't quote the `%` the binding does that for you. As is your query would come out as `WHERE country ='\'%\''` also you need to use `like`, not `=`. With an `=` there is no wildcards. `Like` will perform the same as `=` if no wildcards are used.

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements. Also, `CA` and `NY` sound like states in the United States of America, not countries.

Comment: You can keep " WHERE country=. $SelectedCountry" in a variable and in case of all country you can keep it blank and can concatenate it in your query.

Comment: @chris85 this is awesome! I removed the qoute like you said and it works.:)

Comment: @EdCottrell I am indeed using Prepared statement and using the `Like` operator, just messed up with my explanation sorry

Comment: Yes please @chris85

Comment: @jay If you have code like `$SelectedCountry = $_POST["country"]; sql .= " WHERE country=" . $SelectedCountry;`, then you are missing the point of prepared statements. A prepared statement doesn't do anything magical to sanitize input that you have directly concatenated into the query. The point is to use placeholders and bound parameters. Try it yourself with a value like `0 OR 1 = 1` and see what happens. Your code is extremely vulnerable.

Comment: @EdCottrell no that's just an example :) I had to prepare an example in a way that I don't get responses like "Why aren't you using this instead" etch. I needed answer to the proper use of wildcards in MySQL statements but if I post my actual codes I'd get answers to a different question instead but I definitely use prepared statement PDO. Thanks to all the hackers out there lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is not a wildcard in SQL when comparing with the `=` operator. You can use the `like` operator and pass a `%` to allow for anything.

When doing this the `%` should be the only thing going to the bind. `$Bind_country = "'%'";` is incorrect because the driver is already going to quote the value and escape the quotes. So your query would come out as:

```
WHERE country ='\'%\''
```

The `=` also needs to be a `like`. So you want

```
$bind_country = '%';
```

and then the query should be:

```
$sql = 'select * from table where country like ?';
```

If this were my application I would build the `where` part dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Using `*` in `WHERE` clause is not right. You can only give legit value. For example:

```
// looking for an exact value
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'value'


// you can also do this when looking for an exact value
// it works even if your $_POST[] has no value
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'value' OR '$_POST["country"]' = ''


// looking for a specific or not exact value
// you can place % anywhere in value's place
// % denotes the unknown characters of the value
// it works also even if your $_POST[] has no value
// results will not be the same when you're using AND or OR clause
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%val%'
```

Comment: `OR $_POST[] = ''` <- what's that? o_O

Comment: @zerkms Oh geez! I forgot to put `$_POST[]` in quotes, sorry about that (if that's what you meant). What I mean with `$_POST[]` is `$_POST['country']`. That statement, in case the post has no value, will be `' ' = ' '` resulting to displaying all the data if the first statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think below link can solve your problem.
Just have a look and choose what you need.
Thanks.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp